# mod_rewrite country code into URI

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I need to redirect the following URL which has the country code at the start:

```
http://xx.domain.com/test.html
```

into:

```
http://xx.domain.com/xx_en/test.html
```

I came up with the following, of course this will have an infinite loop:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/xx_en/ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([^.]+)\.domain\.com [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) /%1_en/$1 [R=301,L]
```

So I added the first line which, I think, means if you don't see /xx_en/ in the request_uri then do what follows.

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Quick question: All the country codes you have is two-letters only? Also, in `!/xx_en/` xx here is symbol for any country code. Right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use something like the following set of rules:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([^\.]+)\.domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/%1_en/.*$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /%1_en/$1 [R=301,L]
```

You can understand it like: for all requests to all 3rd level domains under domain.com which doesn't start with /<3rd level>_en/ redirect to it...